# Override file.less Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

Hi all, I'm trying to override the CatalogSearch module with a css style only for the module.
From Magento's documentation says to create folders and files this way /_/web/css/source/_module.less
My path is root_theme\Magento_CatalogSearch\web\css\source_module.less
I have this path with this file and the code inside to try this is

```
 button {background-color: chocolate;}
.action {
    .primary{
             background:#333;
             }
}
```

but it does not work.
How can I solve this problem?
Magento_CatalogSearch\web\css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct path is:

```
<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_CatalogSearch/web/css/source/_module.less
```

After you ave included the file. Remove the content of:

```
/pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/<locale>
```

and

```
/var/view_preprocessed
```

and finally run:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```